# In an iOS SpriteKit game using Swift, how to free up memory taken up by textures that are no longer in use?

Tags: swift, memory-management, sprite-kit, textures

I am making a game with SpriteKit using Swift. The game contains 20 mini-games that the user can play one-at-a-time. Each mini-game uses its own texture files. The textures for one mini-game can take up as much as 150 MB of memory. As the user moves from one mini-game to the next, how do I free up memory taken up by the textures used in the prior mini-game?

Comment: if you are using SKTextureAtlas's then the system manages the memory for you, you just need to make sure you are not using any objects in a texture.  If at least 1 texture of an atlas is in use, then the entire atlas will sit in memory.

Comment: KnightOfDragon, thanks for your comment. Can you explain what you mean by using objects in a texture? Do you mean something like: let someTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"some_texture.png"); someSprite.texture = someTexture; ???

Comment: I mean if you use any texture or subtexture in an atlas then it will stay in memory

Comment: I see, ok. thanks. I only group miniGame01 textures with other belonging to the same miniGame01. Then I do something like this: let someTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"some_texture.png"); someSprite.texture = someTexture;

Comment: then start learning how to do atlases, you can group each mini game textures into their own atlases

Comment: yes, thanks. I am now putting textures for the same mini-game in a folder named mini_game_01_textures.atlas and then copy the whole folder to XCode.

Comment: it is a bit more complicated than that,  Use the image assets in your project to properly make them